# Revmob banner is covering the keyboard

Tags: ios, keypad, revmob

I have an issue with keypad. The kay pad is covered by the revmob add banner.

I am using below code in Appdelegate

```
+ (void)basicUsageShowBanner {
   [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];  
}
```

How i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a know bug from RevMob SDK, try to use a banner view as described on the [documentation](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/api/ios/Classes/RevMobAds.html#//api/name/banner).

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712637/issue-with-revmob-add-and-kayboard/21887627#21887627