# RevMob Banner Showing above the keyboard IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, revmob

I am using RevMob, and calling it using `[[RevMobAds session] showBanner];` The problem is, when i call it and already have text fields in the view, if i press inside of the field for editing and the keyboard shows up, the banner will cover most of the keyboard preventing me from using many keyboard features.. how can i fix the position of the rev mob, can i do such a thing ? it seems like that banner just occupies the footer region regarding less what i contains…what can i do ?

Comment: i thought this was better as a comment: http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html

And i think your answer is to search for this on the page:

"You can also change the size and location of the banner, just check the example in the API docs." and api docs is clickable

Comment: It's possible to raise the entire view up when the keyboard shows. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965580/move-view-when-so-that-keyboard-does-not-hide-text-field

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug for their SDK for a long time ([check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721013/revmob-banner-is-covering-the-keyboard)), you have to use a RevMobBanner object, checkout the [official documentation](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/api/ios/Classes/RevMobAds.html#//api/name/banner).